# Conglomerate javascript module export file for Vue modules

Tags: javascript, vue.js, module

How can I create a conglomerate component export file and only load the ones that I need?

I am trying to have a single place where I can import all of my custom UI Vue component. I want to be able to do this:

```js
import {
  Component1,
  Component2
} from './uiComponents'
```

I have a javascript file that does work, but the problem is that if I import anything from this file then all the exported components load even if I'm not using them.

Here is what my conglomerate component exporter looks like:

```js
// uiComponents.js
export { default as Component1 } from './ui/Component1';
export { default as Component2 } from './ui/Component2';
export { default as Component3 } from './ui/Component3';
export { default as Component3 } from './ui/Component4';
export { default as Component3 } from './ui/Component5';
``

but if I import even a single one of those, then the entire thing gets added to my component package
```

Comment: This totally depends on how you build the app. In the best case scenario it works like you expect